# Calculate the smallest integer with k bits set that is greater than another integer x?

Tags: c, algorithm, integer, bit-manipulation

I want to calculate the smallest integer with exactly `k` bits set, that is greater than another integer `x`.

For example if `x = 1001010` then
for `k=2`, the answer should be `1010000`
for `k=4`, the answer should be `1001011`
and for `k=5` the answer is `1001111`

I think that one would need to set at least as many bits as the leftmost bits set in the integer `x`, and then choose between setting the MSB-side bit adjacent to the next leftmost set bit in `x`, or setting the next leftmost set bit and then look at setting the bits following that by repeating the same process; all the while counting the bits left out of the k.

I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: providing sample input/output will make your question much more easier to understand. Do you mean the two integers should have same number of bits set?

Comment: @xvatar I think `x` and `k` are both inputs for the program, that is, `x = 1001010`, `k = 2` would return `1010000`

Comment: should the answer contain exactly k bits set, or at least k bits set?

Comment: @xvatar I realized I should have been more clear in my question. I have made the appropriate changes.

Comment: @EitanT No this isn't homework :-) . This occurred to me while I was solving a related problem that I had been asked in an interview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
++x;

while (popcnt(x) > k)
{
    // Substitute the least-significant group of bits
    // with single bit to the left of them
    x |= x-1;
    ++x;
}

unsigned bit = 1;
while (popcnt(x) < k)
{
    x |= bit;
    bit <<= 1;
}
```

---

Second loop may be optimized:

```
for (i = k - popcnt(x); i != 0; --i)
{
    // Set the lowest non-set bit
    x |= x+1;
}
```

Comment: @ffao: there are lots of such tricks in "The art of computer programming, vol 4A" by D.Knuth. Or in ["Matters Computational"](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/#fxtbook).

Comment: @EvgenyKluev Thank you for the answer and for introducing me to gcc popcnt. I didn't know about that and would have probably written a loop to count the set bits.