# next lexicographic permutation of k with constraint 'greater than or equal to number g'

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

i have a bit mask k, for example 01100011.
i have an index j, which indicates the most significant bits i want to save, for example taking 011 in 01100011 ==> j=2.
I'd like to find the smallest lexicographical permutation of k greater than g = ((k >>(k.len-1-j))+1)<<(k.len-1-j) with a bit manipulation formula, where k.len is the length of the bitmask (8 in the example).

Examples,

```
k = 01100011
for j = 2 ==> g = 10000000 because k>>(k.len-1-j) is 011
solution is 10000111
--------------------------------
k = 01100011
for j = 4 ==> g = 01101000 because k>>(k.len-1-j) is 01100
solution is 01101001
--------------------------------
k = 01100011
for j = 7 ==> g = 01100100 because k>>(k.len-1-j) is 01100011
solution is 01100101
```

I'd like to know the formula and if possible a simple explanation of how the formula is built.

I found in http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation
the formula for the next lexicographical permutation of a number k, i'm looking for something similar to that.

Would be nice if uses only bit operators and not compiler/architecture dependant instruction (i'm using java), but not essential.

Comment: This question would be more clear if you told us the value of g, and the correct answer in your worked example.

Comment: @samgak thanks, edited and corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution adapted from C to Java based off the answer to this question: [Calculate the smallest integer with k bits set that is greater than another integer x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057326/calculate-the-smallest-integer-with-k-bits-set-that-is-greater-than-another-inte?rq=1)

```
public static int smallestIntGreaterOrEqualToXwithKBitsSet(int x, int k)
{
    while (Integer.bitCount(x) > k)
    {
        // Substitute the least-significant group of bits
        // with single bit to the left of them
        x |= x-1;
        ++x;
    }

    for (int i = k - Integer.bitCount(x); i != 0; --i)
    {
        // Set the lowest non-set bit
        x |= x+1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

I've changed the logic from "greater than" to "greater than or equal" by removing the first increment of `x`.

To use this to solve your problem, you can pass in your value of g as the first parameter, and the bitcount of k as the second one:

```
public static int nextPerm(int k, int j, int len)
{
    int g = ((k >>(len-1-j))+1)<<(len-1-j);
    return smallestIntGreaterOrEqualToXwithKBitsSet(g, Integer.bitCount(k));
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(nextPerm(0b01100011, 2, 8)));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(nextPerm(0b01100011, 4, 8)));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(nextPerm(0b01100011, 7, 8)));
```

Output:

```
10000111
1101001
1100101
```